# Wordpress managing custom sections

Tags: html, wordpress

Let's say I have a home page on which there is menu. Below it some text (added via Page) and below that a footer. If I want to add a custom section below the content (let's say one DIV with background image and text on top of it) that user could change, how would I do something like that? Or if I want to create DIV with background image and some text on top of it.

I am familiar with custom posts and custom fields, but that seems like an overkill for something like this.

Basically, I am looking for the easiest solution on which I could manage several "custom" sections (6-7) all over the site.Those sections would basically only be text, images and links. Maybe creating 6-7 widget places and then assigning their places where I need.

Comment: _“Maybe creating 6-7 widget places and then assigning their places where i need...”_ – if you don’t want to use custom fields, then widgets would be what I’d suggest as well. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget: _“This template tag displays an arbitrary widget outside of a sidebar. It can be used anywhere in templates.”_ – so if you can live with having to write HTML code yourself (widgets don’t support WYSIWYG-editing, at least not out of-the-box – there might be plugins for that), then that would be a solution that doesn’t require much coding. […]

Comment: […] To display certain widgets only on specific pages, you can either use [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) inside your template(s), or use an additional plugin such as [Display Widgets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-widgets/).

Answer (score 0):

Purchase a theme with Visual Composer (or integrate the Visual Composer plugin to your site yourself - not for beginners). Visual Composer will allow you to easily create divs with text and images by simple clicks and drag/drop capabilities.